# Lists: using better slicing to find iterative sums of subsets

Tags: python, list, slice, reduce

Say I have a list,

```
A = range(1, 6) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`B`, the end result, is a list of lists. Given `i` and `j`, how would you make a list of iterative sums where index `i` bounds one side and `j` the other?

`B[j] = sum(A[j:i+1] or A[i:j+1])` depending on whether `j` or `i` is larger.

Examples for indices 0 and 2:

```
B[0] = [1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4, 1+2+3+4+5]
     = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
B[2] = [1+2+3, 2+3, 3, 3+4, 3+4+5]
     = [6, 5, 3, 7, 12]
```

======

Current code (works) is two `for` loops, very brute force. I think there should be a way to use `reduce`?

```
A = range(1,6)
n = len(A)
B = []
for j in xrange(n):
    b = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        if j <= i:
            b.append(sum(A[j:i+1]))
        else:
            b.append(sum(A[i:j+1]))
    B.append(b)

# print
for b in B:
    print b
```

Minor context: possibly part of my solution to project euler 82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up recalculating the sums many times.  Instead create them once and look them up for each element of `b`:

```
A = range(1,6)
n = len(A)
mapping = {}
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(i,n):
        mapping[i,j] = sum(A[i:j+1])

B = []
for j in xrange(n):
    b = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        if j <= i:
            b.append(mapping[j,i])
        else:
            b.append(mapping[i,j])
    B.append(b)
```

you could eliminate the need to check `j<=i` if you just make the mapping work for both `[i,j]` or `[j,i]`:

```
mapping = {}
A = range(1,6)
n = len(A)
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(i,n):
        mapping[i,j] = sum(A[i:j+1])
        mapping[j,i] = mapping[i,j] #for both ways

B = [[mapping[i,j] for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
```

Although notice that this means that every `B[x][y]` will directly coordinate to `mapping[x,y]` so you may just want to use the mapping by itself.